# all task has parent task in c#,that is right?

Tags: c#, task, parent

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = string.Empty;
        Task t = new Task(() => {
            x = "dd";
        });
        Task<int> cT = t.ContinueWith<int>(gg => {
            return 23;
        });


        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(cT.Result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The Result:23.
Yes,i want it.
so,i can say all task has parent task in c#,that is right?

Answer (score 2):

`t` doesn't have a parent task, so no: you can't say that "all task has parent task". Those that are *continuations* will have a parent task.

Comment: He has basically reassigned `cT` to `t` - making both reference the same task.

Comment: @Killercam well, now quite; not least, `cT` and `t` are different types. There are two distinct tasks here. There is no result from the first task.

Comment: // System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
public TResult Result
{
 get
 {
  if (!base.IsCompleted)
  {
   Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency();
   base.Wait();
  }
  base.ThrowIfExceptional(!this.m_resultWasSet);
  return this.m_result;
 }
 ...
}

Comment: what is the meaning of base?

Comment: `base` is the super-class (the base type) - it just means that `Task<T>` is inherited from `Task` (no `<T>`), and the `Wait` method is defined in `Task`, not `Task<T>`.

Comment: Thank you very much!i see,and can i say all instances of Task are children of Task?(All of instances of Task are inherited from Task)